# Having trouble with my sites Logo on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The Site is [here](http://stoiximatakias24.gr). The problem is with Logo, on chrome it is displayed ok on the left but on internet explorer somehow it gets in the center. Somehow another test blog of the same theme [here](http://new1231233.blogspot.gr/) seems ok. I really cant find the code that makes the difference and wonder if anybody here can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is Ronaldo :( . No, really, out of jokes, it works fine in IE11, so I assume you mean an old version. Try adding text-align:center to #header

Comment: well , i have ie 11 too but it seems like this http://postimg.org/image/vh05638fv/. Just changed text-align:left to center but didnt work. Is it only my laptop? Google chrome is ok.

Comment: I rolled back the edit; the question isn't meaningful without the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your floats.

```
#header-wrapper { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Dont know a lot on HTML and CSS. Can you describe what was the fault?

Comment: You have .navtime set to float left and #header-wrapper to float left as well. Elements set to float will try to position next to each other if possible unless cleared. I don't know why it was treated differently between the browsers but I guess that comes with the territory.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using many display block? you have to take care with this, it's happing due the bad  structure from your css style. So pay attention with your divs float and about inherits.

Comment: Well the theme came that way so i would have to work with that... :/

Comment: hummmm, i got it, i think you wont have much difficult to fix it.

Comment: everything is difficult for a newbie...i have worked a lot on it to bring it like it is today. if i had a little knowledge more maybe i would save all these hours...iam not a professional yet but i intend to be someday :)